# Calculating the standard deviation of the sum of a series of randomly distributed variables

Tags: probability, standard-deviation, chaos-theory

Say I roll a six-sided dice 100,000 times.

I know that the resulting sums will be normally distributed around a mean of 3.5

How would one go about calculating the standard deviation of the distribution of those sums?

Answer (score 1):

The mean square for a single roll is $(1+4+9+16+25+36)/6=91/6$, so the variance is $91/6-(7/2)^2=35/12$. The variance of the sum of independent random variables is the sum of their variances, so the variance for the sum of $100,000$ rolls is $100000\cdot35/12$, and the standard deviation is the square root of that.

Comment: Thanks!! Now, say I wanted to find the variance for a single roll of an infinity-sided die... Would it follow the same formula?

((Summation of (x^2) ; where 1<x<y) / y) - ((y+1)/2)^2  ; where y=infinity

Comment: @Alex: You'd first have to say what you mean by that.